# Trouble with simplifying trigonometric / hyper-trigonometric functions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Why (correct) expressions like

```
Assuming[p > 0, 2 ArcTan[Sinh[p]] == Pi - 2 ArcTan[Csch[p]] // FullSimplify]
```

Are not correctly evaluated to: True?
What is the best approach in these cases

Comment: Note that the simpler expression `Assuming[p > 0, 2 ArcTan[p] == Pi - 2 ArcTan[1/p] // FullSimplify]` *does* evaluate to `True`.  The problem seems to be that Mathematica doesn't recognize $\sinh x = 1/\mathrm{csch}\, x$ in this context.

Comment: `Series` shows that the difference between the LHS and RHS is zero, i.e.,  `Assuming[p > 0,
  Series[
   2 ArcTan[Sinh[p]] - (Pi - 2 ArcTan[Csch[p]]),
   {p, 0, 50}]] // Normal` evaluates to `0`

Answer (score 1):

Your have to help a bit to FoolSimplify[]

```
f[e_] := 100 Count[e, _Gudermannian | _Csch, {0, Infinity}] + 
      LeafCount[e]

Assuming[p > 0, 
 FullSimplify[2 ArcTan[Sinh[p]] == Pi - 2 ArcTan[Csch[p]], 
  ComplexityFunction -> f]]
```

(*True*)